# THREE JS TWEEN JS not smooth

Tags: javascript, three.js, tween

Im using TWEEN on THREE JS https://github.com/sole/tween.js/ and facing smooth problem.

when i pot tween number from 1 to 2 i get this numbers:

[image]

You can see numbers are sometimes overtaken. That prevent to have smooth animations.

This is my scene animation config:

```
function animate() { 
          requestAnimationFrame( animate );
          render();
          controls.update();
          TWEEN.update();
          stats.update();      
    }

    function render() {      
          renderer.clear();
          renderer.render( scene, camera );
          updateHUDSprites ();
          renderer.clearDepth();
          renderer.render( sceneOrtho, cameraOrtho );                                                           
    }
```

TWEEN function:

```
  var lineTween = new TWEEN.Tween({value:1}).to({value:1000},100).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None).onStart(function(){

  }).onUpdate(function () {
             console.log(this.value);  
  }).onComplete(function () {

  }).start();
```

Is the some experience with this? Why can it be?

Comment: Is your frame rate high enough ? May be the problem  is about performance and not the tween library

Comment: what is your `TWEEN.Easing` function

Comment: its 60, means the max always, scene is smooth, the same when moving camera

Comment: added tween function to question @gaitat

Comment: Problem solved I launched function twice. OnmouseDown and OnmouseUp again. THX.